# Moving data within Typed Arrays

Tags: javascript

Are there any native methods to move data around within typed arrays? For example if I want to "remove" 4 elements from somewhere within the array and then shift everything after down 4 indexes (like memmove in C). Or would this have to be written in Javascript? What do you think would be the fastest/efficient way to do this?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_array.asp  here you will find complete array properties and methods in javascript

Comment: TYPED arrays, not regular arrays.

Comment: what do you mean by typed arrays? there are no typed arrays in javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Well I've looked through the docs and specs that I can find, but as far as I can tell there aren't any methods to move data around within typed arrays. Here's my best guess at a "fast move" function. You'll have to ensure that the supplied ranges are valid, but it should work whether the source index is before or after the destination.

```
function taMove( a, iDst, iSrc, num ) {
    var i, j, k;
    if( iDst < iSrc ) {
        // copy forward
        for( i = iDst, j = iSrc, k = iDst + num; i < k; ++i, ++j ) {
            a[i] = a[j];
        }
    }
    else {
        // copy backward
        for( i = iDst+num-1, j = iSrc+num-1; i >= iDst; --i, --j ) {
            a[i] = a[j];
        }
    }
}
```